# Change a button element in a paragraph

Tags: javascript, html, button

```js
/*jshint strict:false */
document.getElementById("btn_1").addEventListener("click", function() {
  test(this);
});
document.getElementById("btn_2").addEventListener("click", function() {
  test(this);
});
document.getElementById("btn_3").addEventListener("click", function() {
  test(this);
});

function test(id) {
  var e = document.getElementById(id);
  var d = document.createElement('p');
  d.innerHTML = e.innerHTML;
  e.parentNode.insertBefore(d, e);
  e.parentNode.removeChild(e);
}
```

```css
/* CSS Document */

body {
  background-color: #484848;
}

p {
  margin: 2em 2em;
  color: aliceblue;
}

button {
  margin: 1em 2em;
  color: ghostwhite;
  background: #677762;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

  <title>Line Game</title>
</head>
<p>Als die ersten Menschen auftauchten lehrten wir sie:</p>
<button id="btn_1">Jagen</button>
<button id="btn_2">Fischen</button>
<button id="btn_3">Landwirtschaft</button>
<!--Javascript Time-->
<script src="Javascript.js"></script>

<body>
</body>

</html>
```

So here is all my code. And i want to replace the Buttons to Paragraph after someone clicked them. The old Text from the Buttons should still be there.

Yea sorry for the Dump Question, tried a few hours and get a little tired of trial and error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `test(this);` to `test(this.id);`

```js
/*jshint strict:false */
document.getElementById("btn_1").addEventListener("click", function() {
  test(this.id);
});
document.getElementById("btn_2").addEventListener("click", function() {
  test(this.id);
});
document.getElementById("btn_3").addEventListener("click", function() {
  test(this.id);
});

function test(id) {
  var e = document.getElementById(id);
  var d = document.createElement('p');
  d.innerHTML = e.innerHTML;
  e.parentNode.insertBefore(d, e);
  e.parentNode.removeChild(e);
}
```

```css
/* CSS Document */

body {
  background-color: #484848;
}

p {
  margin: 2em 2em;
  color: aliceblue;
}

button {
  margin: 1em 2em;
  color: ghostwhite;
  background: #677762;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

  <title>Line Game</title>
</head>
<p>Als die ersten Menschen auftauchten lehrten wir sie:</p>
<button id="btn_1">Jagen</button>
<button id="btn_2">Fischen</button>
<button id="btn_3">Landwirtschaft</button>
<!--Javascript Time-->
<script src="Javascript.js"></script>

<body>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

In this code you throw link to element

```
test(this);
```

but you need to throw attribute id

```
 test(this.id);
```